# Get the id of a view as String in onClick event

Tags: android, xml, view, onclick

Hi im trying to get the ID i set on each of these linear layouts but instead im getting

android.widget.LinearLayout@41032a40 or similar which isn't much use to me.

I have set the id to row1, and thats what i would like to return.

Im sure I've done something similar before, so i cant figure out why it is returning the above.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gridview"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/row1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dip"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:onClick="xmlClickHandler" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/row2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dip"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:onClick="xmlClickHandler" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/row3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dip"
    android:background="@android:color/black" 
    android:onClick="xmlClickHandler" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/row4"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dip"
    android:background="@color/white" 
    android:onClick="xmlClickHandler" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/row5"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dip"
    android:background="@color/yellow" 
    android:onClick="xmlClickHandler" />
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/row6"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dip"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:onClick="xmlClickHandler" />
```

```
        public void xmlClickHandler(View v) {
    Log.d("CLICK ROW", String.valueOf(v));
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want just the string "row(n)" to be displayed in each row?

Comment: Why do you need id as a string?

Comment: Because i would like to know specifically which linear layouts have been clicked, maybe i should use a table for this but since there is no highlighting in touch mode the method remains the same. I want the user to touch each layout depending on a question (i.e. touch the red and black bars) and i will need to save which ones have been pressed somewhere. Returning the ids as numbers has little context for me as the developer. I need to see, row 1, row 3, row 4 instead of numbers that will make things complicated.

Comment: Defining an id will always create a set of characters to associate with a readable string e.g. row1, row2, etc., in your case. They're auto-generated in your R.java file. Using `android:text@string/row1` will give you the actual string. I don't think you can alter the ID's in R.java...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to set `android:tag="row1"` and use `Log.d("CLICK ROW", String.valueOf(v.getTag()));` to print the id.

Comment: This is the method i've found, was buggy at first kept duplicating tags when i clicked different views but works now.

Comment: Gives out 'nul' for me.

Answer (score 15):

View ID can be checked using v.getID()

You can simply check as

```
   if(v.getId()==R.id.row1)
```

and perform your desired task accordingly.

Answer (score 10):

You can do it in this way:

```
public void xmlClickHandler(View v) {
    String viewID = getResources().getResourceName(v.getId());
}
```

And than you have to parse the result string.

Answer (score 2):

use `v.getId()` instead to get the Id

Comment: 04-25 18:04:01.600: D/CLICK ROW(1244): 2131230726

Still getting numbers back. Have i not set the id's correctly?

Answer (score 2):

The Simple Solution which is just a one-line code. It can Fetch any id from the view.

```
String id=id=getResources().getResourceEntryName(view.getId());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Log.d("CLICK ROW", String.valueOf(v.getId()));
```

`v` is an instance of the View class, and you can use the `getId()` method to get the View's ID.

Comment: 04-25 18:04:01.600: D/CLICK ROW(1244): 2131230726

im still getting the numbers back when i want row1, row 2 etc

Any ideas?

Comment: @user2066039 All IDs are numbers. You can compare it to your IDs like if(v.getId()==R.id.row1)

Comment: Yeah unfortunately that makes things complicated for me. I may use this method if tags dont work.

Answer (score 0):

I've just seen another question, apparently you cannot return the id as a string.